# PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW in junit5 doesn't work

Tags: java, junit5

This code runs normally in the program, but cannot be run in junit5 with springboot 2.3.11

```
TransactionUtil transactionUtil = null;
    try {
        transactionUtil = new TransactionUtil();
        transactionUtil.begin(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);
        ...
        transactionUtil.commit();
    }
    cache(Exception e) {
        transactinUtil.rollback();
    }

    //method begin() in TransactionUtil
    public void begin(int propagation) {
        DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) SpringUtil.getBean("dataSource");
        transactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
        transactionDefinition = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
        transactionDefinition.setPropagationBehavior(propagation);
        transactionDefinition.setIsolationLevel(TransactionDefinition.ISOLATION_DEFAULT);
        status = transactionManager.getTransaction(transactionDefinition);
    }
```

Comment: This code scares me, as it looks like you are running code which works around all the Spring stuff. Why?

Comment: Please clarify 'cannot be run'. Does not compile? Test errors? Please share the code to reproduce.

Comment: @TomStroemer When running the test case, it will be stuck at the method of begin the transaction, but it works well in my server

Comment: @M.Deinum We only managed the lifecycle of the transaction in springboot manually

Comment: Why? You should do that, let Spring manage that with `@Transactional`.

Comment: On start of a tx it will open a connection your test probably doesn't have a large enough pool or something like that.

Comment: Because when we use multiple data sources to switch, we will encounter problems here @M.Deinum

Comment: it seems that not like this, the pool should not be fill, or it will be throw an exception instead of stuck

Comment: Then you should solve that instead of doing a workaround. Depending on your need that would be XA (distributed transactions) or using multiple transaction managers. The code you shown here doesn't take multiple datasources into account either. If the pool is full or not properly initialized it will eventually time out (I expect). However I would say there is too little information here and that it is (partially) caused by how you solved your problems.